# Управление демоном на linux+python

Tags: python

Есть скрипт бота longPoll.

```
def main():
  #do anything

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Получается, что он должен работать как демон, но в нем должна быть возможность управления, то есть вводить команды в консоль. Это происходит через второй поток. Но запускается скрипт на малине и подключаюсь к ней по SSH, как в таком случае вызывать консоль и какие инструменты есть для данной задачи?

Comment: А зачем вводить команды в консоль? Вводите команды в сокет, который будет прослушиваться этим самым вторым потоком, например

Comment: @andreymal Можно подробнее? Что-то наподобие сервера написать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите на данную библиотеку:
https://pypi.org/project/daemons/

Там же есть пример реализации демона, два различных файла, один - реализует непосредственно функционал демона, а второй принимает сигналы с консоли и управляет процесом